# in Js how to operate on array but also consider the array may be just one element

Tags: javascript, arrays

When an array has multiple elements ['x','y','z'], one can operate on them with forEach or map, but there are scenarios where this 'array' is just one element 'a' and isn't an array.

When apply forEach or map, the code will through error for trying to iterate over a non-iterable. What's the best way to factor in such scenario? Thanks

Comment: Provide more details about use case

Comment: "*this 'array' is just one element 'a' and isn't an array*" - well, just don't do that. It's horrible. If you are absolutely forced to deal with such malformed input, wrap it into an array as soon as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you need to accomplish you might be able to do something like:

```js
const myFunc = (input) => {
  return Array.isArray(input) ?
    input.map(s => s.toUpperCase()) :
    input.toUpperCase()
}

console.log(myFunc(['a', 'b', 'c']))
console.log(myFunc('a'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Array.isArray` method to type check your object before attempting to call array methods on it.

For example:

```
function conditionalMap(element, fn) {
  if (Array.isArray(element)) {
    return element.map(fn)
  } else {
    return fn(element)
  }
}
```